# Laravel 3: Class not found in namespace

Tags: namespaces, laravel, laravel-3

This is the problem: I haven't be able to load a class from a namespace.

I'm developing a restful app and I'm trying to follow the Entity/Service/Repository way to access and give format to the requested data. The thing is that I cannot load any class from Services. I have created a folder inside my app called **api**, and within it the others 3 folders: `api/entities/`, `api/services/` and `api/repositories/`. There are 2 more folders inside services: **validators** and **datapickers**.

As it is a RESTulf app, I also created an api folder inside the controllers folde: `controllers/api/`.

Here is the the current tree of my app folder:

```
app/
   api/
       entities/
       repositories/
       services/
            datapickers/
                MemberData.php
                ConsumeData.php
            validators/
     ...
    models/
    controllers/
       api/
           members.php
           (other restful controllers)
    languages/
     ...
```

In first instance, this is my **Autoload** section from **start.php**:

```
Autoloader::directories(array(
    path('app').'models',
    path('app').'libraries',
    path('app').'api'
));

Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Api' => path('app').'api',
));
```

And this is `MemberData.php`:

```
<?php 
namespace Api\Services\Datapickers;

use Api\Repositories as Repo;

class MemberData
{
     /* Do some stuff */
}
```

Now, when I try to use `MemberData` in `controllers/api/members.php`:

```
<?php
use Api\Services\Datapickers\MemberData;

class Api_Members_Controller extends Api_Base_Controller
{
    public function get_index($id = null)
    {
        if (!empty($id))
            $this->params->data = MemberData::getById($id);
        else
        {
            $this->params->data = MemberData::getAll(
                Input::get('offset'), 
                Input::get('limit')
            );
        }

        return Response::json($this->params, 200);
    }
}
```

I get the following:

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:

Class 'Api\Services\Datapickers\MemberData' not found

Location:

/path_to_project/application/controllers/api/members.php on line 15
```

which is this line: `$this->params->data = MemberData::getById($id);`

I autoload the **api** folder and register the base api namespace in `start.php` but I still keep receiving the same error. IT's like Laravel doesn't recognize the api namespace or something like that.

I tried to register the full namespace:

```
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Api\Services\Datapickers' => path('app').'api/services/datapickers',
));
```

but the error I got was: `Call to undefinde method 'Api\Services\Datapickers\MemberData::getById()'`. This was just a test (I don't want  to register every sub-namespace in the Autoloader).